# Juju: What permissions are needed on a vsphere cloud?

Tags: juju

I'm trying to use Juju to manage our infrastructure in a vsphere private cloud. However when I try to setup the juju controller using the CLI it fails, because of a permission problem.

This is the error from juju:

```
14:54:32 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:519 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "Cluster1": creating import spec: ServerFaultCode: Permission to perform this operation was denied.
```

This is the operation that fails:

```
spec, err := ovfManager.CreateImportSpec(ctx, UbuntuOVF, resourcePool, datastore, cisp)
```

https://github.com/juju/juju/blob/develop/provider/vsphere/internal/vsphereclient/createvm.go#L319

I have no problems importing a Customization specification in vcenter with the same user.

What permissions are required for the user, to be able to use juju with vsphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit.

What was missing was the permission to create VMs from templates.
(Virtual machine > Provisioning > Deploy template)

Source: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-31C6CD2D-41CA-4646-994A-C61AD5FF1880.html